# Search for string in text file and print after space occur in PHP

Tags: php

This might be an easy one but not for me.

I have this function:

```
function pingAddress($ip) {
    // Read from file
    $lines = file('F:\share\result.txt');
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
        if(strpos($line, $ip) !== false)
            echo $line;
    }
}
```

The text file looks like this:

```
192.168.50.104 UP
192.168.50.105 UP
192.168.50.106 DOWN
192.168.50.107 UP
```

If I give ip 192.168.50.1 for example it returns all the lines from 192.168.50.1 to 192.168.50.199 and I need it to return only that specific line and if possible only what's after ip: UP or DOWN.

Help would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), you are accepting partial matches, which causes `192.168.50.1` to match all your examples.

Instead, split the line on a space, and check for a full IP match. Then you can return the UP or DOWN part.

```
function pingAddress($ip) {
    // Read from file
    $lines = file('F:\share\result.txt');
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $parts = explode(' ', $line);
        if($parts[0] == $ip){
            return $parts[1];
        }
    }
}

echo pingAddress('192.168.50.1'); // nothing returned
echo pingAddress('192.168.50.105'); // UP
```

Comment: Is it also possible to add a background color to UP and DOWN? like ```echo "<p style='background-color:lime'>";``` and ```echo "<p style='background-color:red'>";```

Comment: Yes, if you store the return value in a variable you can use a simple if/else like `if($result == 'UP'){ // echo lime } else { // echo red }`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "return;" after "echo $line;" The function stops, after the searched string is found.

```
function pingAddress($ip) {
    // Read from file
    $lines = file('F:\share\result.txt');
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
        if(strpos($line, $ip) !== false)
            echo $line;
            return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check that there is a space after the IP address to ensure it is the full address and not part of another IP.

I've also changed this so that it reads the file a line at a time, so if it finds the IP address it stops reading there (and returns the UP or DOWN).  This saves reading the entire file before searching...

```
function pingAddress($ip) {
    // Add space for search
    $ip .= ' ';
    $fp = fopen("a.csv", "r");
    while ( $line = fgets($fp) )
    {
        // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
        if(strpos($line, $ip) !== false)
            return trim(substr($line, strlen($ip)));
    }
    fclose($fp);
    return '';
}
```